# How to search text from page with next and previous with native javascript on MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

This question can be specified that if I only have native Javascript with `window.getSelection`, `document.createRange`, without any libraries and no `window.find`, how can I implement the search feature with next and previous buttons.

Currently I have this code with Prev and Next button but I have no idea how to do search previous/next effectively. Is there a way not to save the search location in a global variable?

http://jsfiddle.net/8mdX4/1286/

Is there any polyfill of window.find which I can find?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the `textNodes`, its index and the search phrase in global variables. The `searchNext` would just increment the index and reapplied the rage selection.